# refCount : call underlying ConnectObservable.connect() after "n" observers are connected

Tags: java, reactive-programming, observable, rx-java

I'm trying, from a source observable, to split it as two observables. And then zip this news observables .

```
              |
         +--- A ---+
         |         |
         V         V
         B         C
         |         |
         +-> zip <-+
              |
              V
```

From a code point of view :

```
public Observable<Integer> doTheDev(Observable<Integer> A) {

    // share() == publish().refCount();
    Observable<Integer> bridge = A.share().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());

    Observable<Integer> B = bridge.count();
    Observable<Integer> C = bridge.sum();

    return Observable.zip(B, C, (b, c) -> b + c);
}
```

as the [RxJava documentation show](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators#connectableobservablerefcount) : as soon as the first Observable subscribe, `refCount()` will call `connect()` on the underlying `ConnectableObservable`.

Is it possible, by a way, or another, to wait that the 'n'th observable subscribe to call the `connect()` ? (and then don't miss events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try a way to do so. Without  knowing (yet) if a better, simplier solution exist.

I write a new operator wich do exactly the same thing as refCount (in fact, I copied the refCount source code...) but, intead of subscribing on the first subcriber, it only connect on the nth subscriber.

I only change this part of the code in the `call` method of my new operator :

```
if (id >= numberOfSub) {
    connect(t);
}
```

So, in my application, I can use it as follow :

```
private static Observable<Double> averageOf(Observable<Double> data, Scheduler scheduler) {

    ConnectableObservable<? extends Double> hot = data
            .publish();

    // call the underlying connect() after the 2nd subscription
    Observable<Double> bridge = Observable.create(new OnSubscribeRefCountN<>(hot, 2))
            .subscribeOn(scheduler);

    Observable<Double> count = bridge.count()
            .map(Integer::doubleValue);

    Observable<Double> sum = bridge.reduce(0.0, (seed, e) -> seed + e);

    return Observable.zip(sum, count, (s, c) -> s / c);
}
```

You can find `OnSubscribeRefCountN` code here : https://github.com/bric3/demo-rxjava-humantalk/blob/d6227559b36fcafc08c0d8b894584400694d9a15/src/main/java/demo/humantalk/rxjava/operators/OnSubscribeRefCountN.java#L69